# Learning about version control systems, Git, SVN

Tags: svn, git, version-control

I am a basic SVN user now trying to learn GIT for a new position.

I am trying the usual reading docs and watching videos. However after doing all that I still feel that there is a lot that I do not know. I was wondering if there is a place like project Euler for programming languages, that provides a series of exercises that you can do just to increase your confidence and test your knowledge about a version control system.

Something thats generic enough and gets you up to speed with how to do basic things. This could also serve as a comparison point of sorts between multiple VCSs, that would show what things are easy in which VCS.

If there is nothing I was planning to document my journey in learning GIT and the create an exercise of this sort.

Comment: I've used git daily for over two years and I *still* feel like there's a lot I don't know. It's a big system, don't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend [Visual git tutorial I](http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/tools/visual_git_tutorial_1/).

BUT, there was a lot of questions here about GIT, SVN etc., for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183918/any-good-git-tutorials 
[Git tutorial: Understanding git pull and branches (using a specific example repo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807098/git-tutorial-understanding-git-pull-and-branches-using-a-specific-example-repo) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866185/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-on-gits-internals

Answer (score 2):

http://gitcasts.com/

the best way to learn git is to use it. do not be afraid to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I find that **using a graphical interface** as a 'crutch' while you get familiar with any version control system is great help. With something like Git new users can get quickly discouraged by the command line entry which is rather scary if you havent used bash commands before.

I am currently using a mix of **[Aptana 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3)** which includes integration with Github and clearly highlights the files I am making changes to, as well as making it easy to make commits, revert to original versions or diff-merge my changes to compare the current and last version of code.

As an alternative to Aptana: I've used **[Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)** in the past to get familiar with Subversion and I know that there is a version of **[Tortoise Git](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)** available that also integrates with windows explorer.

The reality is that once you start developing with Git you wont have time to do everything on the command line so you may as well get used to one of GUIs. Learning on a graphical interface is an gentler learning curve, you can get confident since you'll be screwing up less often, once you are familiar with the key concepts there you can start trying out more advanced commands that are only available on the command line, I use the following resource when I need to do something out of the ordinary:

http://www.gitready.com/

Answer (score 2):

I find that understanding the concept was the most helpful (stuff like http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/ ), the rest is just remembering commands.

Answer (score 2):

[Git immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/) is a nice tutorial for newbies. It is patterned after the Learn Python the Hard Way book by Zed Shaw.